# Speed Meeting Pairings, part 2

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm an elementary grade teacher and I want to organize a speed meeting event at the start of the school year for the students. Think "speed dating", but for the purpose of getting to know each other instead of dating. There would be 10 times 3 minutes rounds during which six persons from each of the 6 classes would meet 5 other students they hadn't previously met in the speed meeting.

The important thing is of course that nobody sees somebody else two times during those rounds. The 6 classes each have 20 students. Thus, we would make 20 groups of 6 students each round. We could add a rule that a student of a class should not meet others from their own class, but that is optional.

Do you think you could help me figure out how to achieve this? I've tried with trial and error, but I quickly hit a block and I'm afraid it might be long before I find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is titled part 2 because 2 years ago, I asked a similar question for a speed meeting between teachers, which were then paired into groups of three.

Comment: Your question is a variant of the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html), which asks: "Is it possible (and if so how?) to schedule $n$ players in $g$ groups of $p$ players for $r$ rounds such that no player is ever in a group with the same person twice?". This is generally an unsolved problem. The nearest (to your setup) solution I found online was [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20050407074608/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/~wh/golf/solutions.html#10-6-6), for $60$ players in $10$ groups of $6$ players for $6$ rounds.

Comment: Perhaps you could divide the $120$ students into $2$ subgroups of $60$ and just use the solution in my above comment.

Comment: Personally, I'm having a hard time figuring out what you are describing. Are you saying that at any one time 6 students will be selected, and each will have a "line" of 5 other students that they will meet in sequence for 3 minutes each, while the other 84 students do something else?

Comment: @Paul He's saying that at every round, the $120$ students are divided into $20$ groups of $6$ students. At no time can any group include two students who have previously been together in a group.

Comment: @Jens - That doesn't address my question at all.

Comment: @Paul Sorry to hear that. Perhaps you could make your question clearer.

Comment: @Jens - My question is about the information in the *first* paragraph. It is not clear to me what procedure is to be followed here. It is also unclear to me why you thought simply repeating the information in the 2nd paragraph verbatim would somehow clear it up.

Comment: @Paul On each round each student is placed in a new group of $5$ other students. The $5$ other students must be students that particular student has never met before.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the link. The problem with this solution is that it provides 6 rounds, but we wuld really like to get to 10, or at least 8.

Comment: @Paul - For the first round, we prepare 20 tables around which each student is seated. Everybody is at one of the tables and each table holds exactly 6 students. For round 2, everybody stands and goes to the table they've been assigned. When sitting down, everybody realizes everybody else around the table is somebody they haven't seen previously. The same is true for every round after that. In other words, nobody is waiting while the others are chatting for 3 minutes. Once everyone is seated, every table should have exactly 6 people around it who didn't meet in previous rounds.

Comment: Thank you. I was misled by the "speed-dating" reference into thinking the groups of six would undergo a sequence of 1-on-1 meetings between themselves.

Comment: Out of $120$ students there are ${120 \choose 2} = 6140$ different pairings of students. Each table at each round removes ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ pairings for future rounds. With 20 tables, that is $300$ pairings per round. At that rate, it would seem like you could do 20 rounds before you were forced to duplicate pairings. But that is a simplistic analysis, so it can't be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Number the tables $0$ to $19$, and break the students up into six groups of $20$. In each group, every student is assigned a different starting table.

Start with this system:
 - Group A never moves,
 - Group B moves 1 table up cyclicly each round (the student at $19$ moves to $0$),
 - Group C moves 1 table down each round (the student at table $0$ moves to $19$),
 - Group D moves 2 tables up each round,
 - Group E moves 2 tables down each round,
 - Group F moves 3 tables up each round.

This isn't perfect. Make out the Progression Table of the students starting at table $0$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}\text{Round}&\text{A}&\text{B}&\text{C}&\text{D}&\text{E}&\text{F}\\\hline
1 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
2 & 0 &  1 & 19 &  2 & 18 &  3 \\
3 & 0 &  2 & 18 &  4 & 16 &  6 \\
4 & 0 &  3 & 17 &  6 & 14 &  9 \\
5 & 0 &  4 & 16 &  8 & \color{red}{12} & \color{red}{12}\\
6 & 0 &  5 & \color{red}{15} &  \color{red}{10} & \color{red}{10} &  \color{red}{15}\\
7 & 0 &  6 & 14 & 12 &  8 &  18\\
8 & 0 &  7 & 13 & 14 &  6 &   1\\
9 & 0 &  8 & 12 & 16 &  \color{red}4 &   \color{red}4\\
10 & 0 &  9 & 11 & 18 &  2 &   7\end{array}$$

But now it is a fairly simple matter to make 4 arbitrary changes to get unique groupings:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}\text{Round}&\text{A}&\text{B}&\text{C}&\text{D}&\text{E}&\text{F}\\\hline
1 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
2 & 0 &  1 & 19 &  2 & 18 &  3 \\
3 & 0 &  2 & 18 &  4 & 16 &  6 \\
4 & 0 &  3 & 17 &  6 & 14 &  9 \\
5 & 0 &  4 & 16 &  8 & 12 & \color{green}{13}\\
6 & 0 &  5 & 15 & 10 & \color{green}{11} &  \color{green}{16}\\
7 & 0 &  6 & 14 & 12 &  8 &  18\\
8 & 0 &  7 & 13 & 14 &  6 &   1\\
9 & 0 &  8 & 12 & 16 &  4 &   \color{green}5\\
10 & 0 &  9 & 11 & 18 &  2 &   7\end{array}$$

Make this modified table your assignments for table $0$. Students starting at other tables add their starting table number cyclicly to the entries in this table to get their assignments. I believe that should be sufficient to assure unique pairings for everyone. But it is very late, so I am going to bed without checking it.

Comment: If between rounds 5 and 6 people in group E move back one table, they'll be with the same person from group C in both rounds.

Comment: I've tried something akin to that approach. I started with student 0 everywhere, then for round 2, the pairings where (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), for round three, they were (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10) and so on. I see it as a kind of method adjusted with trial and error. The problem is that when you consider all the tables (and not just table 0), I believe that there will be more than only a few mismatches the more you go on. When you solve a mismatch, you happen to create another one somewhere else. Anyway, if nobody finds a solution, that is the approach I'll use. Thanks.

Comment: Looking your method again, perhaps I'm wrong to think that considering all the table will lead to more mismatches. After all, every other table is simply the same as table 0, but with all numbers moved up or down a certain amount... I'll have to make sure.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - you are right. Some other fix will be needed.

Comment: @Jérémie - Peter is correct, this doesn't work as I currently have it described, and it is exaclty for the reason you mentioned. If we could find a set of fixed offsets that never conflict for table $0$, then I think I could prove it works for all start tables, but the conflict fixes cause problems with other tables. And every set of offsets I tried has conflicts. I'll think about it some more later.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who provided comments on the problem. The event is due tomorrow (we decided late to use such a formula for the event), so I'll try tonigh to brute force my way out of this with pairings manually done. Anybody can try to find a perfect resolution, which will be used for next year, should we still have 6 classes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works! Here's the summary of it. I hope I downloaded the image right. Basically, each round, I tried moving everybody up a certain amount of position from the initial round. That's the number we see in each column A to F. When the new match was in conflict with another pairing, I manually found a pairing that would work. This table shows only one person from each class, but you simply have to add 1 to the number shown everytime for the next person, and so on.

I managed to make it to the 10th round. Of course, this is by no means a "resolution" of the problem, but only a solution that happens to work.

Thanks for everybody who contributed.

[image: Speed Meeting modifiers]